# MVC enable-migrations NOT FINDING CONTEXT IN ASSEMBLY

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection

I have two models, one I created in Microsoft SQL Server.... and one I am attempting to manage user roles etc for the application.

I used an approach that considers the `ApplicatonDBContext` for registering, deleting users etc.
I have added the code in the controller and in the `AccountViewModels` in order to create my views.

I now need to enable migrations to update the database, but an error in the Package Manager Console appears:

> More than one context type was found in the assembly
>   'Greenwich_Placement'. To enable migrations for
>   'Greenwich_Placement.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use
>   Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName
>   Greenwich_Placement.Models.ApplicationDbContext. To enable migrations
>   for 'Greenwich_Placement.Models.PlacementEntities', use
>   Enable-Migrations
>   -ContextTypeName Greenwich_Placement.Models.PlacementEntities.

So I use the command:

> use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName
>   Greenwich_Placement.Models.ApplicationDbContext

This error now appears:

> The context type 'Greenwich_Placement.Models.ApplicationDbContext.'
>   was not found in the assembly 'Greenwich_Placement'.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today.  When I enabled migrations, I copied from the output given in the "More than one context" error:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyPoject.Models.ApplicationDbContext.
```

and naturally, received the error

```
The context type 'MyPoject.Models.ApplicationDbContext.' was not found in the assembly 'MyPoject'.
```

Then I realized that there was a period at the end of ApplicationDbContext.  When I removed it the migration worked fine:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MyPoject.Models.ApplicationDbContext
```

Hope your issue is as simple/stupid as mine was!

Comment: @dashstart  saved a lot of time.